# Add Multiple Dynamic Spinner Views in Android Activity,Not Loading Selected Spinner Data In second Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner, dynamic-view

1. In My application i am Having Dynamic Spinners.
2. Totally 2 Spinners are there in a Method,Both are dependent(SPinner1 ,Spinner2).
3. I can call that method multiple Times.
4. Spinner Data Loading from Local database.

**Problem:**

i called that method twice So activity Shown Totally 4 Spinners.

```
       1a.spinner1
       1b.SPinner2

       2a.Spinner1
       2b.Spinner2
```

Based on 3rd Spinner what i Selected , 4th Spinner data is loading perfectly.

but based on **1st Spinner Selected item data Not showing in 2nd Spinner, because last iteration data(3rd and 4th spinner)only stored in String Array**.

Please Help me to Solve this. show data in all the spinners.

**My Method to create Dynamic SPinners**

```
// Helper for inflating a row Dynamic SPINNER

private void inflateDynamic_SpinnerRow(String ObjectidTypeIdVal,final String LabelvalDynamic,String ValidationID,String SavedFormidValString
            , final String FormObjectIDValue)
    {


        Log.i("Dynamic Spinner", LabelvalDynamic+"Form OBJECT Id"+FormObjectIDValue);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView123 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowfor_dynamic_spinner_with_label, null);
        final TextView Textview_Label1 = (TextView) rowView123.findViewById(R.id.textViewa1Labelxml);
        final TextView Textview_Label2 = (TextView) rowView123.findViewById(R.id.textViewa2Labelxml);
        RelativeLayoutDynamic2=(RelativeLayout) rowView123.findViewById(R.id.Realtive2);


        DynamicSpinner123 = (Spinner) rowView123.findViewById(R.id.DynamicSpinner1xml);

        DynamicSpinner123Dependent2=(Spinner)rowView123.findViewById(R.id.DynamicSpinner2xml);


        DynamicSpinnerarr= new ArrayList<String>();
        DynamicSpinnerarr_IdValue= new ArrayList<String>();



      //  DynamicSpinnerDependdentarr= new ArrayList<String>();


        if (!LabelvalDynamic.equals(""))
        {


//Converting string to Array list

                    try
                    {


                        MobileServiceList<th_tbdynamicspinner> results09;
                        results09 = mToDoTable_Form_DynamicSPinner_Table88_Local_Database.read(mPullQuery12378).get();

                        //Offline Sync
                        if(!results09.isEmpty())
                        {


                            Log.i("Data Is Available ", "From Lcoal>>>>>>" + "Data  DynamicSPinner");


                            for (int i = 0; i < results09.size(); i++)
                            {

                                Boolean  mComplete_BooleanState=results09.get(i).isComplete();

                                Dynamic_Spinner_ID_StringVal1_TableValue3=results09.get(i).getDynamic_Spinner_Id_StringOne();
                                Form_Object_ID_StringVal1_TableValue3=results09.get(i).getForm_Object_Id_StringOne();
                                Table_Name_StringVal1_TableValue3=results09.get(i).getTable_Name_StringOne();
                                ID_Column_StringVal1_TableValue3=results09.get(i).getID_Column_StringOne();
                                Data_Column_StringVal1_TableValue3=results09.get(i).getData_Column_StringOne();
                                Data_Condition_StringVal1_TableValue3=results09.get(i).getData_Condition_StringOne();
                                Dependent_SPinner_StringVal1_TableValue3=results09.get(i).getDependent_Spinner_StringOne();
                                FormID_value_StringVal1_TableValue3=results09.get(i).getFormId_Val_StringOne();

                                Log.i("Local Database Listview", Table_Name_StringVal1_TableValue3 + ":" + Form_Object_ID_StringVal1_TableValue3);

                               /* DynamicSpinnerarr.add(Dependent_SPinner_StringVal1_TableValue3);
                                DynamicSpinnerarr_IdValue.add(ID_Column_StringVal1_TableValue3);*/

                                Collections.addAll(DynamicSpinnerarr,Dependent_SPinner_StringVal1_TableValue3);
                                Collections.addAll(DynamicSpinnerarr_IdValue,ID_Column_StringVal1_TableValue3);

                                if(Dependent_SPinner_StringVal1_TableValue3.equals(""))
                                {
                                    Log.i("SPINN", "Spinner Data NotFound from Local");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.i("Listview ", "Dynamic Spinner Data AVAILABLE");

                                    String Data[]=LabelvalDynamic.split(",");
                                    Textview_Label1.setText(Data[0].toString());
                                    Textview_Label2.setText(Data[1].toString());
                                    arrayadpFIrstDynamic=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Form_DetailsAddPage.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,DynamicSpinnerarr);
                                    arrayadpFIrstDynamic.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                    DynamicSpinner123.setAdapter(arrayadpFIrstDynamic);

                                }


                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Log.i("Dyanmic SPinner ", "Data NotFound in Local");

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {

                        e.printStackTrace();;
                        Log.i("Local In Listview", "Exception Occur......!");
                    }

        }
        else
        {
            mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView123;
            //deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            Textview_Label1.setText("NOt Avilable");
        }


/*Item Selected in First Dynamic Spinner :-)*/
        DynamicSpinner123 .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner123, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                try
                {
                    DynamicSpinnerDependdentarr= new ArrayList<String>();

                    String selectedItem = spinner123.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                    for (String member : DynamicSpinnerarr)
                    {
                        Log.i("Member name: ", member);
                    }
                    DYNAMICSPINNER_VALUE_ARRAY=new String[DynamicSpinnerarr.size()];
                    DYNAMICSPINNER_VALUE_ARRAY=DynamicSpinnerarr.toArray(DYNAMICSPINNER_VALUE_ARRAY);

                    DYNAMICSPINNER_ID_VALUE_ARRAY=new String[DynamicSpinnerarr_IdValue.size()];
                    DYNAMICSPINNER_ID_VALUE_ARRAY=DynamicSpinnerarr_IdValue.toArray(DYNAMICSPINNER_ID_VALUE_ARRAY);



                    Log.i("String Selcted",selectedItem);
                    Log.i(" MY ARRAY Selected :-)",Arrays.toString(DYNAMICSPINNER_VALUE_ARRAY));


          /*Finding the Id related to Dynamic Spinner*/
                    for(int i=0;i<DYNAMICSPINNER_VALUE_ARRAY.length;i++)
                    {


                        if(selectedItem.equals(DYNAMICSPINNER_VALUE_ARRAY[i]))
                        {

                            DynamicSpinnerIdString=DYNAMICSPINNER_ID_VALUE_ARRAY[i];
                            Log.i("DYNAMIC ID",DynamicSpinnerIdString);

                            // break;
                        }

                    }


/*For Getting Spinner LocalDatabase Data*/



                    MobileServiceList<th_tbdynamicspinnerdependenttable> results678;
                    results678 = mToDoTable_Form_DynamicSPinnerDependent_Table77_Local_Database.read(mPullQuery1234).get();


                    //Offline Sync
                    if(!results678.isEmpty())
                    {

                        RelativeLayoutDynamic2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        Log.i("Data Is Available ", "From Lcoal>>>>>>" + "Data SPinner");


                        for (int i = 0; i < results678.size(); i++)
                        {


                            Boolean  mComplete_BooleanState=results678.get(i).isComplete();
                            DyncamicDependent_ColumnIDStringVal1_TableValue2 = results678.get(i).getId_Column_StringOne();
                            DynamicDependent_CITYList_VALUE_StringVal1_TableValue2 = results678.get(i).getCity_List_StringOne();

                            Log.i("Local Database Listview", DyncamicDependent_ColumnIDStringVal1_TableValue2 + ":" + DynamicDependent_CITYList_VALUE_StringVal1_TableValue2);

                            Collections.addAll(DynamicSpinnerDependdentarr, DynamicDependent_CITYList_VALUE_StringVal1_TableValue2.split(","));


                            if(DyncamicDependent_ColumnIDStringVal1_TableValue2.equals(""))
                            {
                                Log.i("SPINN", "Spinner Data NotFound from Local");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.i("Listview ", "Spinner Data AVAILABLE");
                                // TextviewLabel.setText(Labelval.toString());
                                arrayadp2_Dependent=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Form_DetailsAddPage.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,DynamicSpinnerDependdentarr);
                                arrayadp2_Dependent.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                DynamicSpinner123Dependent2.setAdapter(arrayadp2_Dependent);

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Log.i("DynamiceSPinner ", "Dependent Data NotFound in Local");

                        RelativeLayoutDynamic2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }


                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("","Spinner Error  OnItemSelectedClick");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });



        DynamicSpinner123.setId(viewsCount++);
        allViews.add(DynamicSpinner123);
        allValidation_arr.add(ValidationID);
        allObjectid_arr.add(ObjectidTypeIdVal);
        allSavedformid_arr.add(SavedFormidValString);
        allformObject_id_arr.add(FormObjectIDValue);

        DynamicSpinner123Dependent2.setId(viewsCount++);
        allViews.add(DynamicSpinner123Dependent2);
        allValidation_arr.add(ValidationID);
        allObjectid_arr.add(ObjectidTypeIdVal);
        allSavedformid_arr.add(SavedFormidValString);
        allformObject_id_arr.add(FormObjectIDValue);


        // Inflate at the end of all rows
        mContainerView.addView(rowView123);

    }
```

Comment: Your code is too much complicated for the given task in hand. It is a two method work. 
First method would add a spinner to existing arraylist of spinners and the second implements the onItemSelected listener for that array of spinners. Having ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> would be good for holding data for each spinner.

Comment: i holding data in array list not a problem,it should reflect data in 2nd dependent Spinner,based on 1st Spinner  selected,Even we r creating Multiple Dynamic Views.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DynamicSpiner extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    //main spinner data
    String firstSpinnerArray[] = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
    //dependent spinner data in arrays
    List<String[]> dependentDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    //initialize main adapter and dependent adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter, adapterDependent;
    //initialize main Spinner and dependent Spinner
    Spinner spinner, spinnerDependent;
    //creating map for dependent Spinner to load the data according to its parent spinner
    HashMap<Integer, Spinner> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Spinner>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynamic_spiner);
        //add data in List for dependentSpinner data
        dependentDataList.add(new String[]{"One-1", "One-2", "One-3", "One-4"});
        dependentDataList.add(new String[]{"Two-1", "Two-2", "Two-3", "Two-4"});
        dependentDataList.add(new String[]{"Three-1", "Three-2", "Three-3", "Three-4"});
        dependentDataList.add(new String[]{"Four-1", "Four-2", "Four-3", "Four-4"});

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DynamicSpiner.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        adapterDependent = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DynamicSpiner.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


        for (int i=0; i<firstSpinnerArray.length; i++){
            spinner = new Spinner(DynamicSpiner.this);
            spinnerDependent = new Spinner(DynamicSpiner.this);
            spinner.setId(i);
            spinnerDependent.setId(i);
            hashMap.put(i, spinnerDependent);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            adapter.add(firstSpinnerArray[i]);
        }
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String getDependentArray[] = dependentDataList.get(position);
        for(String string : getDependentArray){
            adapterDependent.add(string);
        }
        int spinnerId = view.getId();
        if(spinnerId == position){
            Spinner getSpinnerDependent = hashMap.get(position);
            getSpinnerDependent.setAdapter(adapterDependent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

I haven't not tested this. Hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply :) But in my side Based on the Spinner1 selection Spinner2 Data will be Loading from the Local database.

Comment: yes, selected spinner is applied in for loop. according to main spinner it will load the data to dependentSpinner

Comment: Read my Problem Properly  and this thing will Work or not.because Just adding Hard coded values it may work. i want to Use that Method Multiple times based on the Database valueid from First Spinner,then load the Second Spinner data.

Comment: also first Spinner data length is Not Constant,based on local db String Data.

Comment: No one will give exact answer to your question, they only show you a way.

Comment: can you Explain me what is the Wrong in my Code?

Answer (score 0):

before adding views to `mContainerView.addView(rowView123);`
first remove the previous child views.

```
//snippet.

//remove all views
mContainerView.removeAllViews();
//add new views
mContainerView.addView(rowView123);
```

Comment: what is the need of Removing the views?

Comment: my problem is not belongs to view Showing ,Data Loading.